# Are there any Goodness of fit tests for Vine copulas?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, copula

Is there any goodness of fit tests like those based on probability integral transform (PIT) of Rosenblatt available for Vine copulas as a built in function in R?
I know we can use `gofCopula` from `copula` package for bivariate, but how can we do it for higher dimensions or Vine copulas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VineCopula package offers the function RVineGofTest:

"This function performs a goodness-of-fit test for R-vine copula models. There are 15 different goodness-of-fit tests implemented, described in Schepsmeier (2013)."

See the help page for further details.

Schepsmeier, U. (2013) A goodness-of-fit test for regular vine copula models. 
Preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0818

Schepsmeier, U. (2013) Efficient goodness-of-fit tests in multi-dimensional vine copula models.
http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5808

Comment: does the goodness of fit of vine copula deteriorate as number of covariates increases from 5 to say 1,000? I have yet to see an article that uses vine copula for a 10+ variable dataset, I guess because even at that stage there are already so many conditional copula combinations to estimate? Is this why vine copula have not caught on